# Como fazer título de pagina com php

Tags: php

Como posso fazer esse codigo abaixo funcionar da seguinte forma ele funciona pegando no caso o endereço do site media/ ou filmes/ e os GET's ficando assim a url

ex: http://www.enderecodosite.com.br/medias/blu-ray/sobrenarutal/
http://www.enderecodosite.com.br/filmes/avi/todo-mundo-em-panico/

Gostaria de fazer isso funcionar ficando assim

ex: http://www.enderecodosite.com.br/blu-ray/sobrenarutal/
http://www.enderecodosite.com.br/avi/todo-mundo-em-panico/

De forma que ele saiba reconhecer que a 1 URL e de medias e a 2 URL e de filme fazendo assim aparecer seus títulos correspondentes sem que haja a necessidade de ter medias/ ou filmes/ na URL.

```
<?php //
//
//
// DESCRIÇÃO DA LISTA DE MEDIAS INICIO
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($uri, 'media/'.$_GET['media_categoria_url'].'/'.$_GET['media_subcategoria_url'].'/')){
$select1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `media_categoria` WHERE `media_categoria_url`='".$_GET["media_categoria_url"]."'");
$dados = mysql_fetch_array($select1);
$select2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `configuracoes` WHERE `funcoes`='dados'");
$dados2 = mysql_fetch_array($select2); ?>
<title><?php echo $dados2["site_titulo"]; ?> - <?php echo $dados["nome"]; ?></title>
<meta content='<?php echo $dados["site_keys"]; ?>' name='keywords'/>
<meta content='<?php echo $dados["site_descricao"]; ?>' name='description'/>
<? } // DESCRIÇÃO DA LISTA DE MEDIAS FIM
//
//
//

//
//
//
// DESCRIÇÃO DA LISTA DE MEDIAS INICIO
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
elseif (strpos($uri, 'filmes/'.$_GET['filmes_categoria_url'].'/'.$_GET['filmes_subcategoria_url'].'/')){
$select1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `filmes_categoria` WHERE `filmes_categoria_url`='".$_GET["filmes_categoria_url"]."'");
$dados = mysql_fetch_array($select1);
$select2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `configuracoes` WHERE `funcoes`='dados'");
$dados2 = mysql_fetch_array($select2); ?>
<title><?php echo $dados2["site_titulo"]; ?> - <?php echo $dados["nome"]; ?></title>
<meta content='<?php echo $dados["site_keys"]; ?>' name='keywords'/>
<meta content='<?php echo $dados["site_descricao"]; ?>' name='description'/>
<? } // DESCRIÇÃO DA LISTA DE MEDIAS FIM
//
//
// ?>
```

Comment: teria que fazer uma busca relacionada no banco de dados..

Comment: e como eu posso fazer isso ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma boa solução para o que você quer, seria utilizar url amigável.

Sem dúvidas seria uma solução para o que você quer e podes utilizar o módulo de reescrita de url do apache para fazer isso.

Visto que o assunto é um pouco extenso, segue link de apoio que o ajudará nesta solução:
[Documentação oficial do Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)